# Printer on a ARM Linux (CUPS) - general theories/questions

Tags: linux, printing, cups

**Hello,**

I have a theory and I kindly ask the skilled linux users to confirm/deny it (I am not a skileld one at all). Im running:

**Raspberry Pi model B+, Raspbian OS** and **CUPS 1.5.4**

And I bought the **SEWOO LK-TL322** POS printer.

The printer is supposed to support Linux CUPS driver they provide. Ok according to their 2 pages long simple manual (link down) I was able to install the pritner. Worked in 1 min like a charm.

But, with the printer driver, a filter was installed - **rastertosewoo** filter which is failing with every print job, no matter how simple it is **(error message: rastertosewoo filter failed)**. I googled what a **filter** is and found out its a layer of editing the content to be printed to fit the next layer or finally the printer. This is the last layer provided by the manufacturer - guessing from the logs, since its the last filter to be started.

**Theorys / Ideas:**

**1.** Is it possible that the manufacturer says it supports "Linux CUPS" but **does not say that only for some architectures?** That the ARM architecture (raspberry pi) could be a filter issue?

**2.** If it is so, is there a way how to make it work for ARM? (I dont haev the filter sources, I just got a compiled filter) - recompiling the compiled?

**3.** Is there any generic linux "driver" that is simmilar or supports POS printers like this?

**4.** In the manual, the manufacturer informs about these two distro types: (Ubuntu) vs (SUSE, Fedora Core, RedHat) - could Raspbian be a isse (and not ARM)? I have read that Ubuntu and Debian are VERY close and that Raspbian is build on Debian so that should work .. am I correct?

**5.**  I have read, that if a printer supports natively PostScript - it does not really need a driver, adn if my printer would support PS natively I could just add it as **RAW printer** and use it like that. I tried that, I am able to print ASCII but the moment I try to print a image I get a looong (200+ lines) printed output starting

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0
%%BEGIN PROLOG
...
```

Does that mean my printer supports PS or not?

Last info: Yes, I contacted the manufacturer, without response yet and I highly doubt there will be any. Regarding POS printing on linux, I should look for something that supports natively PS and/or is covered in **GHOST printer driver**?

**Thank you** for any inputs or anything that could help me.. I could not sleep and am highly depressed, becasue it works like a charm on windows and doing trouble on linux :(

**Links:**

[Short installation manual](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17524455/nodelete/How%20to%20Install%20CUPS%20Driver.pdf)

[CUPS driver by manufacturer - filter and PPD](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17524455/nodelete/sewoocupsinstall.tar.gz)

Comment: Not really a programming question - try http://SuperUser.com ?

Comment: Hi, you are correct, thank you - I did not know that subsite. Posting there.

Comment: Just a comment. I just installed debian on a x86 machine and tested the driver there. Worked like a charm. So yep some filters have problem with ARM architercure obviously ... Damnit. anyone wants a POS printer? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, the FILTERs are architecture dependent and after contacting the manufacturer he compiled and provided the ARM build for this driver (worked like a charm):

My dropbox link for users facing same problem: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17524455/nodelete/SEWOO_CUPS_ARM_Driver.zip

Comment: Oliver,
the link is dead, can you upload the file again?
Thanks, MZ

Comment: Here you go, sorry: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17524455/nodelete/sewoocupsinstall_arm.tar.gz

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xqsd7egz4vhn4uc/sewoocupsinstall_arm.tar.gz?dl=0